# Output of Struct passed to function

Tags: c, printing, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct Item
{
    int type;
    int power;
    char name[20];
};

struct Player
{
    int level;
    int str;
    int speed;
    int def;
    int intel;
    int luck;
    int hp;
    char name[20];

};
struct Item loadItem();
struct Player loadPlayer();
struct Item loadItem();

int main()
{
    struct Player player1 = loadPlayer();
    struct Item itemList[2];
    itemList[1]=loadItem();
    itemList[2]=loadItem();

    printData(&player1,itemList,2);

//player1 = loadPlayer();

}

struct Item loadItem()

{
    struct Item item;

printf("Please Enter the following item info:\n");
printf("Name: ");
scanf("%s",&item.name);
printf("Type: ");
scanf("%d",&item.type);
printf("Power: ");
scanf("%d",&item.power);
printf("\n");

return item;

}

struct Player loadPlayer()

{
    struct Player player;
 printf("Please enter the following player info:\nName: ");
 scanf("%[^\n]",&player.name);
 printf("Level: ");
 scanf("%d",&player.level);
 printf("Strength: ");
 scanf("%d",&player.str);
 printf("Speed: ");
 scanf("%d",&player.speed);
 printf("Defense: ");
 scanf("%d",&player.def);
 printf("Intelligence: ");
 scanf("%d",&player.intel);
 printf("Luck: ");
 scanf("%d",&player.luck);
 printf("Max HP: ");
 scanf("%d",&player.hp);
 printf("\n");

 return player;
}

void printData(struct Player player1, struct Item itemList[], int listsize)

{
    int i = 0;

printf("Collected Input: \n");
printf("Name\t Lvl Str Spd Def Int Lck MHP\n");
printf("%s\t %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",player1.name,player1.level,player1.str,player1.speed,player1.def,player1.intel,player1.luck,player1.hp);

printf("\n\n");

 printf("Name\t Type Power");
for(i=0;i++;i<listsize)
    printf("%s\t %d %d",itemList[i].name,itemList[i].type,itemList[i].power);

    return;}
```

/*** struct Item loadItem(): This function defines a variable of type Item. The function,
prompts the user for an item
 name, item type and item power,
 storing the values in the variable of type Item and returning it.

struct Player loadPlayer():This function defines a variable of type Player.
The function, prompts the user for all required attributes of the defined variable
(Level, Strength, Speed, Defense, Intelligence, Luck, Max HP, Current HP, and Name).
This function then fills the defined variable with the input and returns the struct.

void printData(struct Player p1, struct Item itemList[], int listSize):
    This function takes a variable of type struct Player  p1, an array of struct Item itemList[],
    and an integer listSize representing the number of items in itemList.
    This function displays all information for p1 and all information for the list of items itemList.
***/

In this program I am creating two struct types, player and item.  Then i initialize one player and two items.  The problem I have is when passing the info to the printData function and trying to print it to the screen the values are not those which i have saved to each object.  Please feel free to compile this code yourself and suggest and changes, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Indexes start from 0, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Item itemList[2];
itemList[1]=loadItem();
itemList[2]=loadItem();
```

must be

```
itemList[0]=loadItem();
itemList[1]=loadItem();
```

Arrays are 0-origin in C.

Moreover:

```
struct Player player1 = loadPlayer();
/* ... */
printData(&player1,itemList,2);
```

You pass a pointer to a structure object in `printData` as its first argumenr but your function declaration is:

```
void printData(struct Player player1, struct Item itemList[], int listsize)
```

that is, your first parameter is a structure object not a pointer to a structure object.

Comment: Thanks ouah, i appreciate it.  I am new to c, and still trying to learn.  Your answer has helped me to successfully output the values of the player.  Although I am getting no output for the items.  any help with this?  I know the name of the array is a pointer itself so i have not passed it as a pointer

Comment: @MichaelSciortino You've mixed up the second and third parts of the for loop header.

Comment: oh my thats kind of embaressing.. i need some sleep.  Thanks alot